# real life image floor tiles

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, objects

What is the best method to apply real photos to floor tiles and other surfaces?
In particular I work with stone slabs, with particular veins.
I have to be able to arrange the images in a certain way and in a certain order, with tiles of certain shapes and sizes. I can't rely on procedural materials.

For now I have only managed to create a floor by designing the tiles in 3d either individually or using arrays.
I had to individually apply a base material to each tile, and then change the "texture image" node of each tile for each of them.
I wanted to understand if this repetitive work of creating materials and setting each image could be summarized in a few steps.

this is what I have done so far, I imported a dxf file with the measurements of a floor of a room. then I created solids for each tile, then I realized that with arrays you can do it faster.
[image: my work]
Instead this is the result I would like to create. as you can see I need to put the textures in a specific position and not randomly.
[image: macchia aperta tiles]

Comment: Hi :). You can make a tile array, and randomly assign textures to the tiles. Please show what you have so far, and what is the intended goal :)

Comment: @JachymMichal thanks for your interest, I updated the post.

Comment: Hey :). Could you create the whole floor texture as an image in Photoshop, and then project it onto the tiles? Or do you need it changeable per each tile?